# forcing non-numeric characters to NAs in numpy (when reading a csv to a pandas dataframe)

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, casting, iopro

I have records where fields (called `INDATUMA` and `UTDATUMA`) are supposed to comprise numbers in the range of 20010101 and 20141231 (for the obvious reason). To allow missing values but retain precision up to the nearest dates, I would store them as floats (np.float64). I was hoping this would force the occasionally misformatted field (think of 2oo41oo9) to `NA`s, but instead breaks the import both in pandas 0.18.0 or IOPro 1.7.2.

Is there an undocumented option what could use? Or else?

The key line for the pandas attempt is

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
treatments = pd.read_table(filename,usecols=[0,3,4,6], engine='c', dtype={'LopNr':np.uint32,'INDATUMA':np.float64,'UTDATUMA':np.float64,'DIAGNOS':object})
```

With the eror `ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 2003o730`.

I tried the following in IOPro, just in case:

```
import iopro
adapter = iopro.text_adapter(filename, parser='csv',delimiter='\t',output='dataframe',infer_types=False)
adapter.set_field_types({0: 'u4',3:'f8', 4:'f8',6:'object'})
all_treatments.append(adapter[[0,3,4,6]][:])
```

But this also breaks with `iopro.lib.errors.DataTypeError: Could not convert token "2003o730" at record 1 field 3 to float64.Reason: unknown`

The datafile starts as

```
LopNr   SJUKHUS MVO INDATUMA    UTDATUMA    HDIA    DIAGNOS OP  PVARD   EKOD1   EKOD2   EKOD3   EKOD4   EKOD5   ICD
1562    21001   046 20030707    20030711    I489A   I489A I509      2                       10
1562    21001   046 2003o730    20030801    I501    I501 I489A  DG001   2                       10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use parameter `converters` in [`read_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_table.html):

```
def converter(num):
    try:
        return np.float(num)
    except:
        return np.nan

#define each column
converters={'INDATUMA': converter, 'UTDATUMA': converter}

df = pd.read_table(filename, converters=converters)
print df
   LopNr  SJUKHUS  MVO  INDATUMA  UTDATUMA   HDIA DIAGNOS     OP  PVARD  \
0   1562    21001   46  20030707  20030711  I489A   I489A   I509      2   
1   1562    21001   46       NaN  20030801   I501    I501  I489A  DG001   

   EKOD1  EKOD2  EKOD3  EKOD4  EKOD5  ICD  
0     10    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  NaN  
1      2     10    NaN    NaN    NaN  NaN
```

Or post-processing with parameter `errors='coerce'` of [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html):

```
df['INDATUMA'] = pd.to_numeric(df['INDATUMA'], errors='coerce')
0    20030707
1         NaN
Name: INDATUMA, dtype: float64
```