# pandas read_table parse_dates: New date column already in dict of another column?

Tags: python, date, pandas, type-conversion

As a potential workaround for a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36006248/938408) (forcing misformatted dates to NAs), I am trying to convert two columns to dates right upon reading in pandas 0.18.0. (The [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_table.html) is unclear whether this is possible, or only a single date index can be compiled from one or more columns.)

I do not understand the error about (one of?) the new date column(s) being already in the dict of an unaffected column.

The importing line reads:

```
treatments = pd.read_table(filename,usecols=[0,3,4,6], engine='c',parse_dates=[[3],[4]])
```

The datafile starts as

```
LopNr   SJUKHUS MVO INDATUMA    UTDATUMA    HDIA    DIAGNOS OP  PVARD   EKOD1   EKOD2   EKOD3   EKOD4   EKOD5   ICD
1562    21001   046 20030707    20030711    I489A   I489A I509      2                       10
1562    21001   046 2003o730    20030801    I501    I501 I489A  DG001   2                       10
```

The error says

```
ValueError: New date column already in dict DIAGNOS
```

Comment: I think you want `pd.read_table(filename,usecols=[0,3,4,6], engine='c',parse_dates=[3,4]`

Comment: I misread the manual! Sorry. Though even then I get a `IndexError: list index out of range` error, even if it's off topic here. Shall I use the column numbers corresponding to the new data frame and not the original data file anymore? `treatments = pd.read_table(filename,usecols=[0,3,4,6], engine='c',parse_dates=[1,2])` works, but does force `NA`s for misformatted `INDATUMA` maintains a column of dtype `object` instead…

Comment: You'd have to either use a converter for both cols or process them afterwards to get the desired dtype